# How to return value then-catch block

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

My Codes below;

I've a then-catch block. My responseArray is a global variable. i got response from functionName function; but i can't use result out of  then block. How can i use then response out of block?

My Codes below;

I've a then-catch block. My responseArray is a global variable. i got response from functionName function; but i can't use result out of  then block. How can i use then response out of block?

```
module.exports = {
 foo1: function(param){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      var result = //some code here
      resolve(result);
   });
 },
 foo2: function(param){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.foo1('abc').then(function(res){
        let response = {
            'item':'ok',
            'result':res.some_field
        };
        console.log(response);  // its ok here. 
        responseArray.push(response); //its ok here too
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
    });
    console.log(responseArray); //nothing in array here
    resolve(responseArray);
   });
 }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0):

First thing to remember is that promises are *asynchronous*. Promises are doing exactly what they say, you are essentially signing a contract (promise) that you will get your data (or error) but not synchronously, but at some time in the future when the computations have finished.

In order to access your `responseArray` you will need to resolve your `foo2` promise (inside of `.then`) and continue the promise chain by calling it, i.e.

```
module.exports = {
 foo1: function(param){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      var result = //some code here
      resolve(result);
   });
 },
 foo2: function(param){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.foo1('abc').then(function(res){
        let response = {
            'item':'ok',
            'result':res.some_field
        };
        console.log(response);  // its ok here. 
        responseArray.push(response); //its ok here too
        resolve(responseArray) // resolve the promise inside of .then
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
    });
   });
 }
};

foo2('someValue').then(response => {
  console.log(response) // this will be your array
})
```

Also, as a side note, ensure you are not falling into the trap of the promise constructor anti-pattern. This is where you unnecessarily turn synchronous code into asynchronous code just for the sake of using "*promises*"

For example, a valid use of a promise would be to convert a callback, like so:

```
const getFile = filename => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

whereas this is unnecessary:

```
const printData = data => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(console.log(data))
  })
}
```

vs

```
const printData = data => {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Read more here: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)